# React | Reusable Dropdown component with Typecript dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to create a reusable dropdown on a button, and allow other to pass whatever data the want to it. It is made with Typescript which I am not very proficient with but I made it work:

**The problem is that the data are not being rendered in a dropdown but in the page underneath it**

The Code

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

import './index.scss';

export interface Props {
  isOpen: boolean;
  options: number;
  data: any;
  select: any;
}

const data = ['one', 'two'];

function HeaderMenuButton<T extends object>(props: Props & T): JSX.Element {
  const { isOpen, options, ...otherProps } = props;
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <i className="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-lg circle" {...otherProps}>
        {data[options]}
      </i>
      <ul className={isOpen ? 'active' : null}> // I think there is something wrong here..
        {data.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i} className={i === options ? 'selected' : null} onClick={() => props.select(i)}>
            {item}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default HeaderMenuButton;
```

UPDATED, Stylesheet...

```
.circle {
  width:3em;
  height:3em;
  border:1px solid  grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

I am also using bootstrap in the application. So a solution from there is possible as well..

Can someone help me with, making it work. I mean what is wrong with it I am not sure. Also, I get this eslint error saying:

```
Non-interactive elements should not be assigned mouse or keyboard event listeners.eslint(jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions)
```

Comment: Can you post the stylesheet?

Comment: Just added the stylesheet...in the description

Comment: What I am thinking is making the functional component a stateful one. And use setState, but now I am having a TypeScript problem... If you can find something relevant please help... thanks!!!